# Gracefully failing if value is not found in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What is a graceful way to fail when I want to access a value from a dataframe based on multiple conditions:

```
#Select from DataFrame using criteria from multiple columns
newdf = df[(df['column_one']>2004) & (df['column_two']==9)]
```

If not value satisfying above condition exists, then pandas returns a keyerror. How do I instead just store a nan value in newdf.

Comment: I'd say an empty dataframe would be more appropriate.  Putting nan somewhere implies a column and index value to put it in and you don't have one.

Comment: If neither value exists, it seems, Pandas should return an empty dataframe with original df columns.

Comment: `KeyError` seems to indicate your column names are not found in `df`. I'd check the spelling and capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of dropping rows where the condition is not met, you want pandas to return a dataframe with rows of `NaN` where the condition is `False` and the original values otherwis, you can do the following.

You can assign a list of `booleans` with length equal to the number of rows of the dataframe to a view on all rows of the dataframe. This will get you `NaN` on the rows which are `False` and the original values for rows which correspond to `True`. If the entire list is `False`, you just get a dataframe full of `NaN`.

P.S. One of the column names is probably off. Even if everything is `False`, it should just return an empty dataframe instead of keyError.

Input:

```
print df1
df1[:] = df1[(df1["a"]>2)&(df1["b"]>1).tolist()]
print df1
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  2  3
2  3  2  3
     a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  2.0  3.0
```